# Quantum version of the Galton Board

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, probability, statistics

If classical particles fall through a Galton Board they pile up in the limit of large numbers like a normal distribution, see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaltonBoard.html

[image: Galton Board]

What kind of distribution would one see, if the particles would obey the laws of quantum mechanics (as a thought experiment) ? Wouldn't interference effects lead to a different distribution than the normal distribution?

Comment: More on a [Galton box](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+galton).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might like [this 110-page paper by me and Alex Arkhipov](http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v009a004/v009a004.pdf), which is all about a quantum bosonic analogue of Galton's board (we even use the same graphic you did -- see Section 1.1!).  In particular, we gave strong evidence that such a board (with an arbitrary configuration of "pegs," and with multiple entry points for the "balls") is exponentially hard even to *simulate* using a classical computer.  This suggests that such a quantum Galton's board (which is now called a "BosonSampler") could be used as a rudimentary, proof-of-principle quantum computer.  And indeed, within the last year the first BosonSampling experiments were done in linear optics (see [here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1177)), although so far only with 3 photons.

To make our argument for computational hardness work, we needed two crucial assumptions:

(1) The "balls" have to be *indistinguishable* particles.  If they're distinguishable, then the distribution for any one individual ball could still exhibit interference fringes.  But once you knew the probability distribution for one ball, the distribution for n balls would just be obtained by sampling from that distribution n times independently -- thereby producing "conventional, classical" Law of Large Numbers behavior.  By contrast, identical quantum particles can famously become "correlated" even if they've never explicitly interacted, as seen for example in the [Hong-Ou-Mandel dip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect).

(2) The "balls" have to be *bosons*.  In that case, their transition amplitudes are given by nxn matrix permanents, the calculation of which is a famous hard problem in computer science.  By contrast, if the balls are fermions, then their transition amplitudes are given by nxn *determinants*, which are easy to calculate classically.

Of course, there's also a "narrower" way to interpret your question, which might be closer to what you were actually asking about!  Namely, rather than an "arbitrary" Galton-like board, we could consider the specific geometry from the figure: so let's say, a network of 50/50 interferometers arranged in a diamond pattern in the plane, with a single source of particles at the top.  And we could then calculate (or, if we're lazier, numerically simulate...) the particular probability distribution over n-particle outcomes that that configuration leads to, under two different assumptions:

(1) That the particles are distinguishable.  (In this case, of course, the problem reduces to working out the distribution for a single particle.)

(2) That the particles are indistinguishable bosons.

(Note that a third case, that the particles are indistinguishable fermions, never arises -- for by the Pauli exclusion principle, n identical fermions couldn't even "fit" simultaneously through the single source at the top.)

If I have some time later, I might work out the answers and post them here -- but in the meantime, anyone else should feel free to do so first.

---

**Addendum:** OK, so let's consider the case of a single quantum particle passing through a "diamond-shaped" network of 50/50 interferometers.  In that case, the probability distribution after n steps will be determined, not by the n<sup>th</sup> row of Pascal's triangle (as in the classical case), but by the n<sup>th</sup> row of what we might call the "interferometric Pascal's triangle."  The latter is defined as follows: let A(i,j) be the j<sup>th</sup> entry in row i.  Then:

A(0,0)=1

A(0,j)=0 for all j≠0

For i+j positive and odd: A(i,j)=A(i-1,j)+A(i-1,j+1)

For i+j positive and even: A(i,j)=A(i-1,j-1)-A(i-1,j)

I'm almost certain that the result will asymptotically approximate the standard behavior for the "quantum random walk on the line": see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0010117v1.pdf) or [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0303081v1.pdf) for good overviews.  In particular, the distribution will *not* look anything like the Gaussian one: instead it should be nearly uniform, except with a bunch of oscillating peaks near the two *edges*, with the size of the peaks getting damped as you move closer to the center.  (See the linked papers for example images.)

A slight caveat is that usual analyses of quantum random walks assume there's a "coin" (i.e., a spin-1/2 internal degree of freedom), whereas I've used a staggered arrangement of interferometers to remove the need for the coin.  I don't *think* that affects the walk's qualitative behavior, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Thank you! Your last reference also led me to this article in Wikipedia with a picture of the distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_walk . However, is it true that neither for the fermion nor for the boson case the resulting distribution can be expressed in closed form?

Comment: Well, I think you can at least get a pretty good approximation in closed form, if you're willing to count special functions as "closed form."